# running async with two tasks using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I wanted to be able to run two tasks inside async each function using the "async module".

for example:

```
async.each(openFiles, function( file, callback) {
    // task 1
    function(){
          callback();
     } 

    function(){
          callback(); // task 2, waits for task 1 to finish 
     }  
}, function(err){
   console.log("done");
});
```

Im using each because Im looping through each value and need apply two asks to each element.

Comment: can't you just perform the two tasks in this one function?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, but you can use `async` again nested inside the first `async` callback to run two tasks in parallel.

Comment: take a look at the other async functions, perhaps [applyEach](https://github.com/caolan/async#applyEach) will do the trick, see also, applyEachSeries.

Comment: Why the downvote? this question seems legit...

Comment: Use either `waterfall` or `series` for your two inner functions. Not sure what the two current answers are attempting to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to run `async.series` inside `async.each`. This will iterate `openfiles` and run the series inside, it will only then progress through the each loop when series has finished.

```
async.each(openFiles, function(file, eachCallback) {
    async.series([

        function(seriesCallback) {
            seriesCallback();
        },
        function(seriesCallback) {
            seriesCallback();
        }
    ], function() {
        eachCallback();
    })
}, function(err) {
    console.log("done");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for the 2-async approach:

```
async.each(openFiles, function( file, callback) {

 async.each([task1, task2], function(task, cb) {

  task(file); // exec tasks 1, 2
  cb();       // one completed

 }, callback); // both completed

}, function(err){
 console.log("done");
});
```

Comment: Why use each and create an array each iteration? Why not use `series`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of javascript callback over here to create dependency of task1 on task2. Something like this:

```
async.each(openFiles, function( file, callback) {
    // task 1
    function task1(function(){
          function task2 (function(){
              //callback of async
              callback();
          });
     }); 
}, function(err){
   console.log("done");
});
```

and your task 1 and task 2 function will take the callback as an argument something like this:

```
function task1(callback){
    //do whatever in task1
    callback();
}

function task2(callback){
    //do whatever in task1
    callback();
}
```

In this way task2 will run only when task1 is complete inside async.each